# how to set the environment variable `JUPYTER_PLATFORM_DIRS=1`?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, google-colaboratory

**I am running a .py file in google colab. Sometimes I can run it successfully but sometimes I get the error below. Can anyone help me fix this issue?**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sculpt_faces.py", line 25, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2282, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 28, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir, jupyter_runtime_dir, secure_write
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyter_core/paths.py", line 176, in <module>
    deprecation(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 87, in deprecation
    warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
DeprecationWarning: Jupyter is migrating its paths to use standard platformdirs
given by the platformdirs library.  To remove this warning and
see the appropriate new directories, set the environment variable
`JUPYTER_PLATFORM_DIRS=1` and then run `jupyter --paths`.
The use of platformdirs will be the default in `jupyter_core` v6
```

This is the result of running "!pip install jupyter-core":

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=5.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jupyter-core) (5.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jupyter-core) (2.5.4)

Answer (score 2):

This warning tells you to set the environment variable.

On Linux this can be done running

```
export JUPYTER_PLATFORM_DIRS=1
```

to [set a environment variable](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/) in a terminal.

Then run

```
jupyter --paths
```

in the terminal, too. Afterwards if you run your tests/code this warning should not appear.

Comment: unsetting it, the warning remains in `jupyter-core-5.3.1`. 
Updating to `jupyter-core-5.5.0` it works as expected.